# How to do left join on several dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, join, left-join

I have a several dataframes with the same name. Each dataframe has one row and two columns. One column is common in all of dataframes. I would like to left-join them together. Assuming the name of dataframes is same. I have no plan on differing their names from each other as they are so many of them and I am just putting a few of them here. Is there any way that i can do left join them and generate the desired output mentioned below?

Here is the dataframes:

```
  col1     col2_4
0  1         2
```

---

```
  col1      col2_9
0  1         10
```

---

```
  col1     col2_1
0   1         12
```

---

```
   col1    col2_3
0    1        5
```

Output:

```
   col1     col2_4    col2_9   col2_1   col_3
0     1        2         10       12       5
```

Code:

```
group = df.groupby([randomcolumnname])
for name, groups in group:
     #do some stuff for groups
     print(groups)
     #I want to join the groups dataframes after this line(some groups dataframes are given above)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need for `left join` [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with list of DataFrames by column `col1`:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

from functools import reduce

df = df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='col1', how='left'), dfs)
print (df)
   col1  col2_1  col2_2  col2_3  col2_4
0     1       2      10      12       5
```

Or for `outer join` create index by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([x.set_index('col1') for x in dfs], axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
   col1  col2_1  col2_2  col2_3  col2_4
0     1       2      10      12       5
```

EDIT:

I think better is use custom function with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
def func(x):
    print (x)
    #do some stuff for groups

    return x


group = df.groupby([randomcolumnname]).apply(func)
```

If not possible, for lsit of DataFrames use:

```
dfs = []
group = df.groupby([randomcolumnname])
for name, groups in group:
     #do some stuff for groups

     print(groups)
     dfs.append(groups)
```

Comment: What about `pd.concat([df1,df2, df3], axis=1)`

Comment: @pygo - it align by indices, not by column `col1`, so not

Comment: @jezrael the problem is i can't make a list out of dataframes. There are too many of them. And the way they have been created is with the for loop and they don't have separate name!

Comment: @user8034918 - it is no problem, only in loop append data to list.

Comment: what is `data`? I believe it should be `dfs.append(i)`. So assuming 'df_new` is the variable that i am working with, every dataframe in my initial post is named as `df_new` since the code i have written led it to this. I just applied your code to create list of dataframe. What has been produced is just the name of column of `df_new` underneath of each present dataframes! that's why i am saying creating list of dataframes is the main issue

Comment: it is not giving me the desired list! as i said in last comment, it is just generating the `column name`

Comment: @user8034918 - Can you add your code to question? I cannot see it, so hard to find problem.